# Why does SVG Path get blurred when I use scale?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg, css-animations

I have an SVG with animated eyes on my website. The eyes have a blink animation made with `transform: scale()`. When I now open Chrome and the eyes blink the path of the eyes sometimes gets blurred. It often happens when I scale the website to 90%, but it is not consistent. I also tried adding `translateZ(0)` and `backface-visibility: hidden;` but nothing helped.

Can I solve this somehow?

Since it doesn't happen consistently I don't know if this Snippet will show my problem. As an alternative, I made a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qnwj8uLm/

```css
.info-eyes {
    animation-name: info-eyes;
    animation-duration: 6s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    transform: scale(1) translateZ(0);
    transform-origin: 0% 75%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
}
  
 
  .info-iris {
    animation-name: info-iris;
    animation-duration: 6s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }

  @keyframes info-eyes {
    0%   {transform:scale(1, 1)   translateZ(0); }
    96%  {transform:scale(1, 1)  translateZ(0); }
    98%  {transform:scale(1, 0.1) translateZ(0); }
    100% {transform:scale(1, 1)  translateZ(0); }
  }
  
  @keyframes info-iris {
    0%   {transform: translate(0%, 0%); opacity: 100%;; }
    25%  {transform: translate(0%, 8%); opacity: 100%;} 
    50%  {transform: translate(8%, 8%); opacity: 100%;}
    75%  {transform: translate(8%, 8%); opacity: 100%;}
    96%  {transform: translate(0%, 0%); opacity: 100%;}
    98%  {transform: translate(0%, 0%); opacity: 0%;}
    100% {transform: translate(0%, 0%); opacity: 100%;}
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="81.7" height="75.3" viewBox="0 0 81.7 75.3">
    <defs>
      <style>
        .a {
          fill: none;
        }

        .b {
          clip-path: url(#a);
        }

        .h {
          fill: #fff;
        }

      </style>
      <clipPath id="a">
        <rect class="a" width="81.7" height="75.3" />
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g transform="translate(40.85 37.65)">
      <g class="b" transform="translate(-40.85 -37.65)">
        <path class="info-eyes" d="M34.8,52.7a7,7,0,1,1-7-7,7,7,0,0,1,7,7" />
        <path class="info-eyes" d="M60.7,52.7a7,7,0,1,1-7-7,7,7,0,0,1,7,7" />
        <path class="h info-iris" d="M25.9,50.6c0-2-2.5-2.4-2.5,0s2.5,2,2.5,0" />
        <path class="h info-iris" d="M51.6,50.6c0-2-2.5-2.4-2.5,0s2.5,2,2.5,0" />
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</body>
```

Comment: At least in Firefox I can't see the blurring. But you can try another kind of animation, using a js library like anime.js or GSAP. Or maybe try the SMIL native animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. I changed the blink-keyframe from `transform:scale(1, 0.1)` to `transform:scale(1, 0.2)` and now the animation works fine.

Snippet:

```css
.info-eyes {
    animation-name: info-eyes;
    animation-duration: 6s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    transform-origin: 0% 75%;
}
  
 
  .info-iris {
    animation-name: info-iris;
    animation-duration: 6s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }

  @keyframes info-eyes {
    0%   {transform:scale(1, 1) }
    96%  {transform:scale(1, 1) }
    98%  {transform:scale(1, 0.2) }
    100% {transform:scale(1, 1)  }
    
  }
  
  @keyframes info-iris {
    0%   {transform: translate(0%, 0%); opacity: 100%;; }
    25%  {transform: translate(0%, 8%); opacity: 100%;} 
    50%  {transform: translate(8%, 8%); opacity: 100%;}
    75%  {transform: translate(8%, 8%); opacity: 100%;}
    96%  {transform: translate(0%, 0%); opacity: 100%;}
    98%  {transform: translate(0%, 0%); opacity: 0%;}
    100% {transform: translate(0%, 0%); opacity: 100%;}
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="81.7" height="75.3" viewBox="0 0 81.7 75.3">
    <defs>
      <style>
        .a {
          fill: none;
        }

        .b {
          clip-path: url(#a);
        }

        .h {
          fill: #fff;
        }

      </style>
      <clipPath id="a">
        <rect class="a" width="81.7" height="75.3" />
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g transform="translate(40.85 37.65)">
      <g class="b" transform="translate(-40.85 -37.65)">
        <path class="info-eyes" d="M34.8,52.7a7,7,0,1,1-7-7,7,7,0,0,1,7,7" />
        <path class="info-eyes" d="M60.7,52.7a7,7,0,1,1-7-7,7,7,0,0,1,7,7" />
        <path class="h info-iris" d="M25.9,50.6c0-2-2.5-2.4-2.5,0s2.5,2,2.5,0" />
        <path class="h info-iris" d="M51.6,50.6c0-2-2.5-2.4-2.5,0s2.5,2,2.5,0" />
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem likely stems from browser optimization. There are some possible solutions, like `will-change: transform`, but in my browser it does not work in your example. A hackish way to force the browser to redraw is to add a `transform: translateZ(0)` right after scaling that is messing the figure:

```css
.info-eyes {
    animation-name: info-eyes;
    animation-duration: 6s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    
    transform: scale(1) translateZ(0);
    transform-origin: 0% 75%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
}
  
 
  .info-iris {
    animation-name: info-iris;
    animation-duration: 6s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }

  @keyframes info-eyes {
    0%   {transform:scale(1, 1)   translateZ(0); }
    96%  {transform:scale(1, 1)  translateZ(0); }
    98%  {transform:scale(1, 0.1) translateZ(0); }
    98.001%  {transform: translateZ(0); }
    100% {transform:scale(1, 1)  translateZ(0); }
  }
  
  @keyframes info-iris {
    0%   {transform: translate(0%, 0%); opacity: 100%;; }
    25%  {transform: translate(0%, 8%); opacity: 100%;} 
    50%  {transform: translate(8%, 8%); opacity: 100%;}
    75%  {transform: translate(8%, 8%); opacity: 100%;}
    96%  {transform: translate(0%, 0%); opacity: 100%;}
    98%  {transform: translate(0%, 0%); opacity: 0%;}
    100% {transform: translate(0%, 0%); opacity: 100%;}
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="81.7" height="75.3" viewBox="0 0 81.7 75.3">
    <defs>
      <style>
        .a {
          fill: none;
        }

        .b {
          clip-path: url(#a);
        }

        .h {
          fill: #fff;
        }

      </style>
      <clipPath id="a">
        <rect class="a" width="81.7" height="75.3" />
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g transform="translate(40.85 37.65)">
      <g class="b" transform="translate(-40.85 -37.65)">
        <path class="info-eyes" d="M34.8,52.7a7,7,0,1,1-7-7,7,7,0,0,1,7,7" />
        <path class="info-eyes" d="M60.7,52.7a7,7,0,1,1-7-7,7,7,0,0,1,7,7" />
        <path class="h info-iris" d="M25.9,50.6c0-2-2.5-2.4-2.5,0s2.5,2,2.5,0" />
        <path class="h info-iris" d="M51.6,50.6c0-2-2.5-2.4-2.5,0s2.5,2,2.5,0" />
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</body>
```